# XCOPY and DEL not working with all shortcut files

Tags: windows-7, cmd

I am trying to copy and delete all shortcuts on the desktop, but it seems to only grab some of them. `.lnk` is the only extension that gives me issue.

```
XCOPY *.lnk Organized\Shortcuts\ /A /M /K /O /X
DEL *.lnk
```

Is there something else I have to do to copy all of the shortcuts?

Comment: Are you sure your problematic .lnk files are inside *your* desktop folder?

Comment: Oh, that was the issue. There are multiple folders for the desktop.